# API works in Postman, but not on a browser

Tags: javascript, python, rest, flask

I created a flask api connecting to my mongodb database.

My initial part of the code looks like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={
  r"/api/v1/*": {"origin": "*"},
})
client = MongoClient(connection_str)
db = client.get_database(db_name)

@app.route("/api/v1/players", methods = ['GET'])
def get_all_players():
    ....
```

This works as I intended when I use Postman, but when I input directly into the browser (`localhost:5000/api/v1/players`), it shows me an error as follows:

[image]

I think this is the reason why my `fetch` doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the problem with SSL certificate.  All you need to do, is add `ssl_context='adhoc'` to your app.run() call.

An example :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```

also you need to install `pyopenssl` in your virtual environment